# Azure App Service - An error occurred while starting the application 03/09/2023

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

Without change anything yesterday my application published at Azure as an App Service just stoped. The error:

An error occurred while starting the application.
.NET Core 4.6.29215.02 X64 v4.0.0.0    |   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting version 2.2.7-servicing-10089    |    Microsoft Windows 10.0.14393

This is a C# application. I tried to publish again, deleted bin and obj, rebuild.

I have no clue what can I do.

I use the application insights to see log but it's shows nothing that I can understand:

[image]

[image]

Decided to update the packages and know I'm facing a infinity loop on authentication:

[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kTw7ywznZd74Ppsvm0BOoCDDADrbzmdrR-kPACgdCEw/edit?usp=sharing)

Any ideas?

Solution: I upgraded from .NET Core. Then I changed some points in appsettings like the people in the comments sad. And I also need to adjust CORS and Claims because the identity server login also changed.

Comment: please provide the code which you have tried?

Comment: I check the log you provided, I saw a lot of `localhost` in application insights. Why ? You have used the application insight key in your local project ?

Comment: Until now, it's worth to check the appsettings.json file in [kudu site.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/resources-kudu#access-kudu-for-your-app)

Comment: Thanks. Solved. In fact localhost are wrong and something points more.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I upgraded .NET Core. Then I changed some points in appsettings like the people in the comments sad. And I also need to adjust CORS and Claims because the identity server login also changed.